# Why is ColdFusion and IIS returning me a blank page?

Tags: windows, iis, coldfusion

I have coldfusion and iis working together now. In IIS I have the coldfusion administrator running inside the default website however when I have other sites added from other projects I have done it returns a blank white page. No errors or anything. I have the static pages enabled which have been some other peoples suggestions but it's just not working. Is there anything else that needs to be enabled? I have checked the security on the folders in the inetpub director and the IIS user is inside the list of users and I have correctly setup the datasources and vasrious mappings for these projects. Has anyone else ever experienced this and know how to fix this?

Comment: have you installed any cf updates/hotfixes ? is so check you installed the ones for the right version, as this is a common reason for blank page is wrong hotfixes. I.e. 9.0 hotfix installed on 9.0.1

Comment: No updates no it's just coldfusion out of the box

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using, and what version of Windows/IIS? Have you run the WSCONFIG tool to install the connector to these other "projects"? How are these other "projects" setup in IIS? As separate sites or as virtual directories off of the main site?

Comment: I know this question is closed, but I had the same issue and this is top in Google. In the end I set up a new subdomain and that one just worked straight away. It seemed to be specific to the binding. Note, I was seeing the requests in CF server monitor. They were returning 200, but blank pages. I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the web.config file, and are all the correct web connector settings in there? If you have to redo a lot of websites you can use the web connector tool that comes with coldfusion to apply the change.

Beyond that I would check if you have any URL filtering that's blocking you, and enable robust errors in iis to see if it gives you anything.

Are you receiving HTML back at all? Even try adding a simple index.html file with hello world in it might point you to a setting inside of iis and if it only effect .cfm files or it effects all pages for those sites.

Comment: Where do I find web.config? and how do I know if all the connector settings are in there?

Comment: web.config file is located in the root for all sites running in IIS. It's kinda like a vhost file for that site. This is inside of IIS 7+ I believe IIS 6 may use separate file in the root to dictate its config.
You will want to make sure you check it against existing documentation on what should be in there. Adobe's website should give you this. If you are uncertain you can always run adobe's web connector tool and this should give you a fresh config file for all sites currently running. Warning! this can take some time to run if you have a lot of sites.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the connector. Launch the connector tool as admin and recreate the connector.

If this fails, try accessing simple html page.